# client is not running and can't be stopped. its current state is starting

Tags: kotlin, visual-studio-code, language-server-protocol

I want to use Kotlin in vscode.
so as **kotlinlang.org** says for installing kotlin I installed **intelliJ IDE** and **Android Studio** but I could not access Kotlin from cmd. so I added Kotlin to the path manually.

after that, I installed [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fwcd.kotlin) extension and [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mathiasfrohlich.Kotlin) extension on vscode. but the extension doesn't show me any suggestions.

[image]

also, [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fwcd.kotlin) extension has some errors:

[image]

I don't know what other information I have to share. I hope be enogh.